# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net and this is my first application. I'm developing an application that manages insurance requests. The model Request contains a file upload. the addRequest adds a request and requires a Member to be logged in. Every time I try to run the addRequest I get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mutuelle.Domain.Entities.Request]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Mutuelle.Domain.Entities.Request'.

Also when I put a breakpoint anywhere in the code and run step by step it actually works, it doesn't stop at any line.

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddRequest()
        {
            Request request = new Request();
            return View(request);

        }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRequest([Bind(Exclude = "file")]Request request, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(request);
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryReader fileReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            byte[] fileb = fileReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

            request.file = fileb;

            RequestService requestMemberService = new RequestService();
            Member member = (Member)Session["logedAd"];
            request.nomMember = member.nom;
            request.eMailMember = member.eMail;
            request.member = member;
            member.listRequests.Add(request);
            requesMemberService.UpdateMember(member);
            request.member = member;
            requestMemberService.CreateRequest(request);

            Session.Remove("logedAd");
            Session.Add("logedAd", member);
            return RedirectToAction("Requests");

        }
    }

    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

And here's the view:

```
@model Mutuelle.Domain.Entities.Request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddRequest";
}

<h2>AddRequest</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Addrequest", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Demande</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nomrubrique, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nomrubrique)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nomrubrique)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.file, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input style="margin-left:0px;cursor:pointer;" type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </div>
        </div>






        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: which line is causing the error? it basically says you are trying to add a list of values instead of one value

Comment: Is it when you redirect to `Requests`? on this line: `return RedirectToAction("Requests");`.

Comment: Just for debugging, in your httppost can you replace  return RedirectToAction("Requests"); with return View(request); and let me know what happens. And please let me know what is the model for your Requests view.

Comment: as @LiranBo suggested, your view is expecting a model of type `Request` and you're probably sending it a `list<Request>`. you need to check your action method `Requests` i.e `RedirectToAction("Requests");` and see if it is returning a single request or a list.

Comment: The problem was with return RedirectToAction("Requests"); indeed. When I replaced it with RedirectToAction("profile") it worked.Thank you for your help.